# Javascript onClick for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am working on a submenu for a nav that I need to be accessible for mobile and tablet devices. I am aware that using onClick="return true" will do the trick, however, I also need my list item to close when the user clicks on the list item. Basically I need it to toggle the submenu. If I add this simple line of Javascript, it will work but the submenu will always remain open. How can I get it to close/toggle the submenu?

```
HTML:
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                <li class="bg"><a class="dropdown" href="#">Menu 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

Javascript:
$('nav li.bg').on('click', function(){
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `click` event  is only fired on `a` elements on mobile devices

Comment: @hindmost info source ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek Quote from [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/): _The click event is sent to an element when the **mouse** pointer is over the element, and the **mouse** button is pressed and released._

Comment: @hindmost but this doesnt mean that only links are clickable in mobiles , anything can be clickable as long as it is visible on sreen.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Mobile doesn't have **mouse** and therefore doesn't support **mouse** events. There _touch_ events are used instead

Comment: @hindmost this is old but your statement is not true - mobile browsers **do** definitely fire "click" events.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`touchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) event which fires on mobile browsers.

```
$('nav li.bg').on('click touchstart', function(){
    return true;
});
```

[**More touch based events**](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be toggling the li as I would've hoped.

Comment: @ShakeelVictor of course it doesn't toggle the li. Because you do nothing in your click function (returning true does nothing).
Maybe have a look at the [jQuery toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 2):

A virtual method for p click:

```
$('p').on("touchstart",p_touch_start);
$('p').on("touchmove",p_touch_move);
$('p').on("touchend",p_touch_end);

function p_touch_start(){
    p_touch_move.cancel_click = false;
}
function p_touch_end(){
    if(p_touch_move.cancel_click) return;
    p_touch_move.cancel_click = true;//avoid somehow repeat call
    //trigger onclick()

}
function p_touch_move(){
    //user is drag page, not click
    p_touch_move.cancel_click = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue after some researching and help. Here is what was updated in my code to trigger this on mobile devices correctly after some updating of my CSS as well:

```
     function is_touch_device() {

     return (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
  }

  if(is_touch_device()) {

    $('.bg').on('click', function(){

      $(this).toggleClass('activate');

      $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
      return false;
    });
  }
```