# Why HTML onclick attribute doesnot work on mobile devices in my project?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a web design template by using the jQuery library.It is properly well and nice on desktop but not in mobile devices.My Problem is when I click on HTML '' element I want to hide the display of some divs,so I done this by using the jquery and It is properly work on desktop but not in mobile devices.(I defined the onclick attribute on HTML '' element,which is a button to hide some divs when I clicked on this button,and call the javascript function from HTML onclick which is defined in said '' element.).Please help me to find my bug.

```
  <div class="page-side">
    <a href="#" id="home" class="icon fa-home active" onclick='BaseManager.reload();StyleManager.select(this,"camera","file");'></a>
    <a href="#" id="camera" class="icon fa-camera-retro" onclick='StyleManager.select(this,"home","file");'></a>
    <a href="#" id="file" class="icon fa-file-text-o" onclick='StyleManager.select(this,"home","camera");'></a>
  </div>
```

```
 select: function() {
    var context,argument,arguments = StyleManager.select.arguments;
    var select,miss,page_display;

    page_display = function(displays={}) {
      var count=0,display = {0:'title',1:'head',2:'gallery',3:'generic'};
      for (display[count] in displays) {
        BaseManager.getElement("#"+display[count]+"").css({'display': displays[display[count]]});
        count++;
      }
    };

    context = arguments[0];
    argument = {
      home: function() {
        page_display();
      },
      camera: function() {
        page_display();
      },
      file: function() {
        page_display({title: 'block',head: 'none',gallery: 'none',generic: 'flex'});
      }
    };
    select = BaseManager.getElement("#"+context.id+"");

    if(!select.hasClass("active")) {
      select.addClass("active");
      for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        miss = BaseManager.getElement("#"+arguments[i]+"");
        miss.removeClass("active");
      }
      if(argument.hasOwnProperty(context.id)) {
        argument[context.id]();
      }
    }
  }
```

```
.page-side a
{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 14.7px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline: 0;
}

.page-side a:hover
{
  color: white;
}

.page-side a.active
{
  color: #19B5FE;
}
```

Here is my github [page](https://minmon.github.io/snapshots) !
Here is my github [repo](https://github.com/minmon/snapshots) !

Answer (score 0):

See this question:  [Javascript onClick for mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453151/javascript-onclick-for-mobile-devices)

U need to use touchstart as event.

:)